# 'TypeError: Right side of assignment cannot be destructured' useContext React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-context

I am working in React Hooks and have encountered a problem with the useContext method. My context class for a MapStyle (using Google Maps API) is as follows:

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from 'react';

const MapStyleContext = createContext();

function MapStyleProvider(props) {
const [selectedMapStyle, setSelectedMapStyle] = useState();

return (
    <MapStyleContext.Provider value={{ selectedMapStyle, setSelectedMapStyle}}>
        {props.children}
    </MapStyleContext.Provider>
);
}

export { MapStyleContext, MapStyleProvider };
```

I have the map component attempting to access the selectedMapStyle property:

```
...
export default function Map() {
const { isLoaded, loadError } = useLoadScript({
    googleMapsApiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_MAPS_API_KEY
});
const { selectedMapStyle } = useContext(MapStyleContext);
...
```

Finally, in the MapStyle component, I am attempted to use the setter setSelectedMapStyle whenever the user changes the value of the radio button:

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { Card, CardBody, Button, FormGroup, Label, Input } from 'reactstrap';
import { MenuContext } from '../../MenuContext';
import { MapStyleContext } from '../mapStyle/MapStyleContext'
import '../Tool.css';

export default function MapStyle() {
    const {setSelectedItem} = useContext(MenuContext);
    const {setSelectedMapStyle} = useContext(MapStyleContext);

    const mapStyles = [
        { 'label': 'Map (default)', 'value': 'default' },
        { 'label': 'Grayscale (Clean)', 'value': 'cleanGray' },
        { 'label': 'Subtle Grayscale', 'value': 'subtleGray' },
        { 'label': 'Ultra light', 'value': 'ultralight' },
        { 'label': 'Clean (no labels)', 'value': 'cleanNoLabel' },
        { 'label': 'Clean (roads)', 'value': 'cleanRoads' }
    ];

    return (
        <div className="tool">
            <Card>
                <CardBody>
                    <div className="clearfix">
                        <h3 className="float-left mb-0 mr-2">Map Style</h3>
                        <Button onClick={() => setSelectedItem(null)} className="float-right" close />
                    </div>
                    <hr />
                    <FormGroup tag="fieldset">
                        {mapStyles.map(mapStyle => (
                            <FormGroup key={mapStyle.value} check>
                                <Label check>
                                    <Input type='radio' name='mapStyle' value={mapStyle.value} onChange={setSelectedMapStyle(mapStyle.value)}/>
                                    {mapStyle.label}
                                </Label>
                            </FormGroup>
                        ))}
                    </FormGroup>
                </CardBody>
            </Card>
        </div>
    );
}
```

I am not quite sure where I am going wrong, but the context props never seem to load in correctly (giving me the type error) when I use this context.

Comment: Did you try `onChange={() => setSelectedMapStyle(mapStyle.value)}`?

Comment: Did you remember to put your `MapStyle` component inside of a `MapStyleProvider`?  You won't be able to access the context if there isn't a provider somewhere above it in the tree.

Comment: @AgustinMoles This did help, thank you!

Comment: @LindaPaiste I did forget to wrap the MapStyle in the Provider. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The problem you've faced here is that the value of the `useContext(MapStyleContext)` is null as of initialisation and you've never wrapped the parent component or the current component inside the `Context.Provider`.

Here is an example:

```js
function Map() {
 return (
  <Context.Provider>
    {/*children */}
  <Context.Provider>
 );
}
```